# How are these animations typically done in Swift / iOS - See image

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, core-animation

What do I need to learn in order to create similar animations to the ones shown in the following picture?

Can some one list all of the technologies involved and possibly a quick process as to how this is done?

[image]

Comment: use something like [MRProgress](https://github.com/mrackwitz/MRProgress) if you are looking for an out of the box solution. If, however, you want to do this yourself, you'll probably work with a `CAShapeLayer` and `CAAnimation` subclass. [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.com) and [CocoaControls](http://cocoacontrols.com) are good places to look for pre-built components.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know about CocoaControls. https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/circleslider

Comment: @ishaq's got the right idea. If your goal is to get it done quickly, I'd suggest the CocoaControls route. If you're not up to speed on CocoaPods, Ray Wenderlich has an excellent tutorial that shows how to implement them.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I will check the tutorial form Ray Wenderlich.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For First animation you can use CAShapeLayer and CABasic Animation and animate key path **strokeEnd**
I builded exactly same you can have look at this link,download and see option **Fill circle** animation https://github.com/ajaykumar21091/AwesomeCustomAnimations-iOS/tree/master/SimpleCustomAnimations

Edit -

The basic idea here is to draw circle using bezeir path and animate the shapeLayer using CABasicAnimation using keyPath strokeEnd.

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    self.drawBezierWithStrokeColor(circleColor.CGColor,
        startAngle: 0,
        endAngle: 360,
        animated: false)
    self.drawBezierWithStrokeColor(self.fillColor.CGColor,
        startAngle: 0,
        endAngle: (((2*CGFloat(M_PI))/100) * CGFloat(percentage)),
        animated: true)
}

  //helper methods.
private func drawBezierWithStrokeColor(color:CGColor, startAngle:CGFloat, endAngle:CGFloat, animated:Bool) {

    let bezier:CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    bezier.path             = bezierPathWithStartAngle(startAngle, endAngle: endAngle).CGPath
    bezier.strokeColor      = color
    bezier.fillColor        = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    bezier.lineWidth        = bounds.width * 0.18

    self.layer.addSublayer(bezier)

    if (animated) {

        let animatedStrokeEnd:CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd");
        animatedStrokeEnd.duration             = (2.0/100)*Double(percentage);
        animatedStrokeEnd.fromValue            = NSNumber(float: 0.0);
        animatedStrokeEnd.toValue              = NSNumber(float: 1.0);
        animatedStrokeEnd.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn)

        bezier.addAnimation(animatedStrokeEnd, forKey: "strokeEndAnimation");
    }
}

private func bezierPathWithStartAngle(startAngle:CGFloat, endAngle:CGFloat) -> UIBezierPath {

    let center          = CGPoint(x:bounds.width/2, y: bounds.height/2)
    let radius          = max(bounds.width, bounds.height)
    let arcWidth        = bounds.width * 0.25
    let path            = UIBezierPath(arcCenter   : center,
                                       radius      : radius/2 - arcWidth/2,
                                       startAngle  : startAngle,
                                       endAngle    : endAngle ,
                                       clockwise   : true)
    return path
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Teepeemm I will edit the answer and add necessary details

Comment: @Teepeemm - Added Code